# Angularjs dialog call another controller function on close

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

AngularJs:

I'm trying to show an edit modal box. For this, I'm using $mdDialog of AngularJs material design. Here is my code:

```
angular.module('main').controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    function loadUser(){
       ...
    }

    function showEditSale(index) {
        var sale = $scope.user.Sales[index];
        $mdDialog.show({
                clickOutsideToClose: true,
                fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen,
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                locals: {
                    sale: sale
                },
                templateUrl: 'front/templates/user/edit-sale.html',
                controller: 'UserSaleCtrl'
            })
            .then(function(answer) {
            }, function() {
            });
    }
}]);
angular.module('main').controller('UserSaleCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope, sale){
     $scope.sale = sale;

     function updateSale(){
         ...
         **Need to reload user**
     }
}]);
```

When I click on edit button against user sale, I call **showEditSale** passing the index of user.Sales item. A popup is displayed and I can edit values there. When clicking on update, an api is called which is updating sale information.

The problem is I want to reload this user. To reload, I have to call function from another controller.

My questions are:

1. Is there another way to pass data to dialog box instead of injecting in controller?
2. Do I have to use emit event of AngularJs to call function of another controller?
3. Can I somehow use same controller? I tried but I think $scope is being reset for modal dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I added following code in UserSaleCtrl:

```
function updateSale(){
     ...
     $rootScope.$broadcast('reloadUser');
}
```

Added following code in UserCtrl:

```
$scope.$on('reloadUser', function(event) {
    loadUser();
});
```